# How to stop a shell script (running a infinite loop ) from python?

Tags: python, shell, sh

I have a shell script (test.sh -> example shown below) which has a infinte while loop and prints some data to screen.
I am calling all my .sh scripts from python and I need to stop the test.sh before calling my other commands 
I am using python 2.7 and linux system is on propritary hardware where I cannot install any python modules.

Here is my test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
while :
do
        echo "this code is in infinite while loop"
        sleep 1
done
```

Here is my python Scripts

```
import subprocess as SP
SP.call(['./test.sh'])    # I need to stop the test.sh in order for python to
                          # go and execute more commands and call  
                          # another_script.sh
# some code statements

SP.call(['./another_script.sh'])
```

Well, quick google search made me look into subprocess call and Popen modules . and Popen has a terminate option and it doesn't work for me (or) I'm doing something wrong here

```
cmd=['test.sh']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
p.terminate()
```

Any other suggestions on how I can stop the test.sh from python are highly appreciated

PS: I don't mind to run the test.sh for like T seconds and then stop it

Comment: Are you sure you need to **stop** your shell process? Maybe you want to just run in another thread?

Comment: The "terminate" call sends a SIGTERM signal to the child process.  If you google a bit further, you might find "kill", which sends a SIGKILL to the child, on Linux-like systems.  However, SIGTERM should have worked unless there is something unusual about the script to ignore those signals.

Comment: From your comments in the code: "I need to stop the test.sh in order for python to go and execute more commands and call  another_script.sh". Why then call `test.sh` in the first place, if you want to stop it? Don't you need its results? See also the first comment about using a different thread.

Comment: In other words: what is your *actual* use case for stopping the script, instead of waiting for it to complete and its results?

Comment: @00  'test.sh' is a shell script from the upstream code which is like a startup script and display a particular result every 1 second. I can get those results with different set of commands (once the initialization variables are set ).  And these results update every second and kept in a while loop and I am not authorized to change that script.. only option is to workaround

Comment: @swstephe . Thanks . I will use kill and see if it kills the child process.

Comment: @BlueRineS ..  I am not realy sure about it.. Thought it would be easy to go , istead of going for another thread. Its just I never did multi threading..I will look into it now

Comment: Multithhreading is an **extremely** simple process. The easiest approach could be to subclass the Thread(), and copy the shell running loop into the run() method of that class. Then simply instantiate your subclass and 'start()' it. Now it runs in another thread while you may resume your other code in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

I use tmux for these type of processes, python has a good package [libtmux](https://github.com/tmux-python/libtmux) which should solve your problem.

Basically you create a tmux session:

```
import libtmux
server = libtmux.Server()
session = server.new_session(session_name='my_session_name')
```

then you create a window to run the command in

```
window = session.new_window(attach=False, window_name='my_window_name')
command = './my_bash_file.sh'
window.select_pane('0').send_keys(command, enter=True)
```

You'll be able to run subsequent commands right after this one. To access the tmux session from your bash terminal use `tmux attach -t my_session_name` you'll then be in a tmux window, the one which ran your bash script.

To kill the tmux window use `window.kill_window()` there's a lot of options look at the libtmux docs.

The project [aileen](https://github.com/aileenproject/aileen-core/blob/master/aileen/box/utils/tmux_handling.py) has some useful tmux commands if you want to see some more implementations.